# How can I find the word count in a vector using scala?

Tags: scala

I want the word count in vectors, for example,

My Vectors are:

```
Vector(pen, pencil, pen pencil)
Vector(pencil, book, eraser, pencil book, pencil eraser, book eraser, pencil book eraser)
Vector(pen, pencil, book, pen pencil, pen book, pencil book, pen pencil book)
```

I want the count as,

```
(pen,2)
(pencil,3)
(pen pencil,2)
(book,2)
(eraser,1)
(pencil book,2)
(pencil eraser,1)
(book eraser,1)
(pencil book eraser,1)
(pen book,1)
(pen pencil book,1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick solution (may not be the most efficient, if that is a concern):

```
val v1 = Vector("pen", "pencil", "pen pencil")
val v2 = Vector("pencil", "book", "eraser", "pencil book", "pencil eraser", "book eraser", "pencil book eraser")
val v3 = Vector("pen", "pencil", "book", "pen pencil", "pen book", "pencil book", "pen pencil book")

(v1 ++ v2 ++ v3).groupBy(v => v).mapValues(_.size)

res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(pencil book eraser -> 1, pencil eraser -> 1, eraser -> 1, book eraser -> 1, pen pencil -> 2, book -> 2, pen pencil book -> 1, pencil -> 3, pen -> 2, pen book -> 1, pencil book -> 2)
```

Comment: Note `groupBy(v => v)` is equivalent to `groupBy(identity)` .

Comment: @Shadowlands it works...but I got these vectors after completed some process. So we can't dynamically store it in a variable.ie, val v1, val v2 ...etc...so wat to do?

Comment: @rosy, do you mean you have a list of vectors? `.flatten` will turn that list into a single list of words, and you can call groupBy on that.

Comment: @Paul one more doubt plz... how to count the number of words in each tuple? ie, for example (pencil book eraser,3), the number of words =3 & (book eraser,5), the number of words in this tuple = 2. How to do this?

Comment: @rosy,Look at the split method for a string.